# Closed Connection Error 17008

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to execute a query which takes huge amount of time sometimes which causes closed connection, meaning the connection gets closed before the query executes/commits. I want to recover from the error, get a new connection and then retry.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.ensureOpen(OracleStatement.java:4051)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1473)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:406)
    at com.fimt.sat.testora12date.dao.DateSaverGetterDao.testAbandonedConnectionWithDS(DateSaverGetterDao.java:73)
```

Comment: Maybe catch exception, and redo query ;)

Comment: I don't think this will do it. As it may retry on th same connection which was closed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try catch this particular error:

```
public save(MyData data) {

    try {
        ...
    } catch (SQLRecoverableException e) {
        // Better handling a parameter to set
        // the maximum number of retries
        // Eventually consider to retry on a secondary thread 
        // delayed of a certain number of seconds
        save(data);
    }

}
```

Comment: But the current transaction will be lost and if query takes much enough time it will be an infinitive loop that don't make sence, am I right?

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich the transaction is already lost if the this exception has been thrown. In any case nobody says that this operation is part of a transaction. It can be a single atomic operation and retrying it is absolutely possible.

Comment: Yes, but with oracle you can tune RAC or some kind of. I'm not prof in that field

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO I am retrying the method exceution by applying recovery startegy but the same error again happens, so I am not sure if the mthod retry is happening using the same connection which was closed.

Comment: @RajkumarMadasu if you don't create (or better retrieve) a new Connection in the method you will have a not valid connection.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Davide Lorenzo MARINO is great unless you have a query heavy enough to not to manage to be executed even after such several recovers.

I'm not a professional in Oracle but what I've found is that you can tune some kind of RAC failover that will keep you transaction even after exceeding the timeout.

But generally my vision is that it is better to split data somehow in multiple queries

Comment: The datasource we are using is RACAware. Ideally what we want to do is get a new connection and retry the same method which has the query that was failing.

Comment: @Rajkumar Madasu ok, then Davide Lorenzo MARINO answered you question I guess

Answer (score 0):

Better split / bucket the data in the select query and commit at some intervals. E.g if the query is for a duration of 2 months, bucket it / loop / split it 15 days of period and do the necessary statements and commit it

Comment: Actually this doesn't happen all the time.The reason this happens is there are like hundreds of threads running at the same time withe same query and once in a while this query may take longer than expected due to lot of traffic from/into data base at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the following error upon connection to DB and accessing the tables.
"An error was encountered performing the requested operation"
Closed Connection
Vendor code 17008.

Was able to resolve this after downloading the latest version of SQL Developer 19.2.1.247. Earlier older version was 3.x.